# Junit 4.11 TemporaryFolder constructor with java.io.File

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit4, temporary-directory

I am trying to do this.
and it ids working fine in eclipse but gives error in maven.

Sample Code

```
File baseFolder=new File("C:\BASE_FOLDER");
temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder(baseFolder);


//Error in maven
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor TemporaryFolder(java.io.File)
[ERROR] location: class org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder
```

Any links or hints will be helpful.
Thanks.

Full Error:

```
symbol  : constructor TemporaryFolder(java.io.File)
location: class org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a JUnit dependency in your maven build.

Comment: What is the full error message with Maven? Run with the -X argument.

Comment: Please see full error in my edit.

Comment: do you have the junit dependency in pom.xml

Comment: Yes I have. Even I checked the TemporaryFolder.class file for constructor in .m2 directory and it is there.

Comment: Does this folder exist already? Do you have sufficient privileges to create one in your root `C:`? Try to use local directory located somewhere in your project ierarchy.

Comment: Have you tried from root user?. If folder is there then delete it and reinstall your dependencies.Try it. It works for many times.

Comment: It is giving me compilation error and it is not a runtime execution error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `TemporaryFolder` is a [TestRule](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html), you use it together with the `@Rule` annotation. From the [Javadoc](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html):

```
public static class HasTempFolder {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
        File createdFile = folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
        File createdFolder = folder.newFolder("subfolder");
        // ...
    }
}
```

or if you would like to specify the location:

```
File baseFolder = new File("C:\BASE_FOLDER");
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder(baseFolder);
```